# Http take longer on flutter but faster on postman

Tags: flutter, dart, http, postman

Please can someone help me out here?
am using http package but my request takes 12429 ms which is so slow.
but on postman, it is just 1199 ms
[image: devtool flutter]

While postman
[image: postman]

I ran it on a real device and an emulator but its very slow but on postman response are very fast.
i expecting it to be as fast as postman